# Cross referencing from a different Overleaf project

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf, xr

I have two Projects, lets call them Project_A and Project_B in Overleaf. Project_A in overleaf has many tex files and so does Project_B. Could a cross reference be made in Project_A such that we could access the tables/figues in that tex files present in Project_B ?

Comment: no, but I think with a paid account you could sync both projects with a git or dropbox repository and so keep thetwo projects in sync that way (but I only have the free version)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This isn't about syncing. but referencing a figure or table

Comment: oh I thoughtyou meant reference as in sync the project you mean reference as in `\ref` ? you could use `\href` from hyperref package to link to the figure in the pdf from the other project if you have placed that at a public URL, otherwise what output do you want?

Comment: I was talking about \ref. In Overleaf, how would you access a table/figure in a different project using the xr package ?

Comment: you can't. not unless you copy the aux file over (which gets back to my first comment)  You can of course just `cite` it as you would any other document for which you don't need a source